# GLTF Unsupported extension: KHR_lights_punctual

Tags: export, gltf

I want to use a Gltf export in Online 3D Viewer, and this works just perfectly, but when I try to implement lights it says "Unsupported extension: KHR_lights_punctual".

I was wondering if there is an option to make a Gltf export but change the way lights are being exported.

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: @Leon you might be in need of a newer online viewer.  KHR_lights_punctual has been the only official way to export lights to glTF files for many years now.  Check if there's a newer version of the software you're using to display the glTF.